# ImageView retuning nil

Tags: ios, swift, null, uiimageview

I have a view controller `OtherUserAccountViewController` containing a button with a "profile picture" as its background. When this button is tapped, I would like to push a new view controller `ImageTappedViewController` onto the stack to simply present a bigger ImageView of this said profile picture. Please note the Storyboard identifier for the screenshot seen below is in fact "imageTapped" and the class is `ImageTappedViewController`

Below is my function for instantiating and pushing the new view controller:

**In OtherUserAccountViewController.swift:**

```
@IBAction func profilePicButtonTapped() {

    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "SuccessfulLogin", bundle: nil) //SB name: SuccessfulLogin

    let cc = (sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imageTapped")) as!  ImageTappedViewController

    if cc.imageView == nil || cc.imageView == UIImage() {
        print("Nil") //<- Nil is printed upon firing this function
    } else {
        print("not nil")
    }

    //cc.imageView.image = self.profilePicButton.currentBackgroundImage <- breaks because the imageView is nil

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cc, animated: true)
}
```

**ImageTappedViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class ImageTappedViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

I am totally lost as to why this imageView is returning `nil`.

I set the imageView to display the lovely Taylor Swift on default as seen below; but regardless, `nil` is being returned.

[image: ImageTappedViewController]

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When view controllers are first initialized their `IBOutlets` will not be initialized. Only after `viewDidLoad` will all of their outlets be non-nil. Pass the image as a `UIImage` then in `viewDidLoad` set image view's image property.